# Get the type of numeric object properties as strings in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

Having an object similar to this:

```
const obj = {
   1: "one",
   2: "two",
   3: "three",
}

type Keys = keyof typeof obj; // type of Key is 1 | 2 | 3
```

How do I get `Keys` to be of type (strings) `"1" | "2" | "3"` in order to have autocomplete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *TypeScript 4.1*, it is possible to use [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

```
const obj = {
   1: "one",
   2: "two",
   3: "three",
}

type Keys = `${keyof typeof obj}`;
const value: Keys = "1";
```